# Today widget showing "Unable to Load" when debugged in iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, today-extension

I have a Today widget in my app, and while it seems to work consistently in released versions (through TestFlight, App Store), it refuses to work when I try to download a new version using Xcode, either to the simulator or to a real device, instead just showing "Unable to Load" in the Notification Center, and my breakpoints are not hit.  If I long press the app icon, the widget does run as expected, so this leads me to believe that for whatever reason, the Notification Center isn't even executing the code.  How am I actually supposed to debug the Today Widget?  If I hit the Run button in Xcode, it seems to just reload the springboard and not actually run anything.